# Black border on TRectangle when I try to put a rounded corner

Tags: firemonkey

I have a TRectangle without the borders. I set `sides` property all to false and it gets like the picture below.

[image: TRectangle without border]

When I set `XRadius` and `YRadius` to 20 the `TRectangle` gets a rounded corner as I desire, however, it gets a tine black border as you can see in the picture.

[image: TRectangle with rounded corner]

I would like to know how to get rid of this tiny black border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not set all sides to false, but instead set `stroke.kind` to none